# Flutter upgrade fail

Tags: flutter

When I attempt to update Flutter I get the following error.

> error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten
>   by merge:
>     examples/flutter_gallery/ios/Runner.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj
>
> Please
>   commit your changes or stash them before you merge.
>
> Aborting Updating
>   f9bb4289e..5ab9e7072 Process finished with exit code 1

I suspect at some point I did something in the examples project and I don't care about loosing the changes.

What is the easiest thing to do?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Go to your flutter *home directory* and do `git checkout .` or `git reset head --hard`

Comment: If your index is corrupt, rm .git/index then git reset

Answer (score 18):

In the Flutter install directory please run

```
git clean -xfd
git stash save --keep-index
git stash drop
git pull
flutter doctor
```

Answer (score 16):

I had the same problem and `git reset --hard origin/beta` in the flutter home directory fixed it.
In my case `git status` revealed that `"You have unmerged paths."`

Note that for the stable branch you need this:

```
cd $FLUTTER_HOME    
git reset --hard origin/stable
```

Comment: The only answer that helped me actually. I had (I don't know how) changed files inside version control. After this cmd, I was able to run flutter upgrade!

Answer (score 2):

Below worked with me to get [1.0.0-stable](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/tree/stable):

```
$ git clean -xfd
$ git checkout origin/stable
$ git pull
$ flutter doctor
$ flutter --version
Flutter 1.0.0 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 5391447fae (5 days ago) • 2018-11-29 19:41:26 -0800
Engine • revision 7375a0f414
Tools • Dart 2.1.0 (build 2.1.0-dev.9.4 f9ebf21297)
```

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me too! What i did that worked was to rename `flutter.gradle` to anything e.g `flutttttterrrr.gradle` then run `flutter upgrade` command again.

The file is located at `C:\your_flutter_location\flutter_main_folder\packages\flutter_tools\gradle`

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

This simply means that you have modified some file from the flutter sdk, to know the modification navigate to the location where you have flutter sdk installed,and enter the command `git status` and you will see the name of the files in red color that have been modified e.g for me it was dropdown.dart

[image]

you can remove those changes by adding it to stash by running the command
 `git stash`

And now again when you run 
`git status` it should prompt you saying

`nothing to commit, working tree clean`

And now you are good to run

`flutter upgrade` and get your hands on the latest contributions from the flutter community.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was adding Dart-SDK path *C:\Users\Profile-Name\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk* to **Environment Variables** under **System Variables**. Double click on Path, click on **New** and add/paste your *dart-sdk path*. Finally open terminal with admin priviledges and run *flutter doctor*.

Answer (score 0):

Just inacese someone is still facing this issue. I found a workaround

commit and push your code changes.

download the latest flutter sdk stable version.

end adb in task manager and close visual studio code.

Rename the previous flutter folder to something like "flutter_old".

Paste the new downloaded flutter to src folder.

open Visual Code and run flutter doctor and flutter packages get and you are updated.